# Check how many clicks have occurred on a bit.ly link present in a particular tweet

Tags: twitter, bit.ly

Consider an app where you maintain a leader-board for users of your app.
Your app has 10 bit.ly links, that a user must tweet.

If the user tweets a link, he gets 5 points. So far I have figured how I must do this, and this is running inside the app properly.

The second functionality of the leader-board app is, to add 2 points to the user's account, if the link shared by the user is clicked.

For instance,

- User A shared the bit.ly link http://bit.ly/1yowZ54 on twitter
- User A gets 5 points
- **Find the number of clicks on the link shared by User A and award**
  `numberOfClicks * 2` **points to User A**

I want a solution for the last step. Is there any way, where I could find how many times the shared link was clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a + to the end of the `Bit.ly` URL.

For example, http://bit.ly/1yowZ54+ will take you to a stats page showing how many clicks a link has had.

There is a [comprehensive API available](http://dev.bitly.com/link_metrics.html) should you wish to do this programatically.